# Making a integer (and tuple) list from string list in Python

Tags: python, tuples, trie

I'm trying to make a int (and tuple) list from a string list.
Let me explain what I'm planning to do and what makes it difficult for me to do it.

### My Coding Plan

#### A. My function (myFunc) takes a string list as its argument.

```
   >>> STRINGS = ['GAT','GAC','ATCG','ATA','GTA']  
   >>> myFunc(STRINGS)
```

#### B. Then, myFunc arrange all the characters in a 'special' way and it returns a new character list (RESULT).

1) 'GAT' - the first string

- All the characters of the first string in the list are selected.
  RESULT = ['G','A','T']

2) 'GAC' - the second string

- 'G' in 'GAC'
  The next string is STRINGS[1]. (== 'GAC')
  Compare STRINGS[1][0] with all the first characters in prior strings(PRIOR).
  In this step, PRIOR includes only 'GAC'.
  If STRINGS[1][0] == STRINGS[0][0], 'G' in 'GAC' can't be appended to RESULT.
- 'A' in 'GAC'
  'A' is the second character in 'GAC'.
  Check if there is a string in the PRIOR whose second character is 'A'.
  In this step, it is 'GAC'.
- 'C' in 'GAC'
  'C' is the third character in 'GAC'.
  Check if there is a string in the PRIOR whose third character is 'C'.
  In this step, there is no string in PRIOR.
  So 'C' can be appended to the RESULT.
  RESULT = ['G','A','T','C']

3) Iterate this process with all the remained strings in the STRINGS.

- RESULT = ['G','A','T','C','A','T','C','G','A','T','A']
- In this list, I can number all the characters.
  NUMBERS = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

#### C. Transform NUMBERS and RESULT to advanced data structures.

I got RESULT and NUMBERS in previous steps.
In this step, those lists should be transformed to advanced data structures.

```
RESULT = ['G','A','T','C','A','T','C','G','A','T','A']  
NUMBERS = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]  
[(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (2,4), ... ] or {(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (2,4), ... }  
{(0,1):'G', (1,2):'A', (2,3):'T', (2,4):'C', ...}
```

### What is difficult for me to implement.

Plans can be difficult when the lengths of strings varies.
Comparing characters with those of prior strings are not easy enough.
Transforming a int list to tuple, Trie, Graph...

```
# SUMMARY  
# Sorry, this is not a code.
# This shows how a string list is transformed to int (and tuple) list.

# 'GAT'  ->  'G,A,T'  ->  1,2,3   ->  1,2,3  ->  (0,1),(1,2),(2,3)  
# 'GAC'  ->  '-,-,C'  ->  -,-,4   ->  1,2,4  ->  (0,1),(1,2),(2,4)  
# 'ATCG' -> 'A,T,C,G' -> 5,6,7,8  -> 5,6,7,8 ->  (0,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,8)  
# 'ATA'  ->  '-,-,A'  ->  -,-,9   ->  5,6,9  ->  (0,5),(5,6),(6,9)  
# 'GTA'  ->  '-,T,A'  ->  -,10,11 -> 1,10,11 ->  (0,1),(1,10),(9,11)  

# ['GAT','GAC','ATCG','ATA','GTA']
# -> ['GAT','C','ATCG','A','TA']
# -> ['G','A','T','C','A','T','C','G','A','T','A']
# -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
# -> tuple list
# -> change tuple list to ordered set
# -> apply this to Python graph and Trie structures.
```

I would like to apply this to the Graph and Trie structures in Python. It will be grateful for any hint or advice. Thanks.

---

Updated in 2015.04.15
I wrote a code to get an int list from a string list.

```
def diff_idx(str1, str2):
    """
    Returns a maximum common index number + 1 
    where the characters in both strings are same 
    >>> diff_idx('GAT','GAC')
        2
    """
    for i in range(min(len(str1), len(str2))):
        if str1[i] == str2[i]:
            i += 1
        else:
            return i
    return i

def diff_idxl(xs, x):
    """
    >>> diff_idxl(['GAT','GAC','ATCG','ATA'],'GTA')
        1
    """
    return max([diff_idx(s,x) for s in xs])

def num_seq(patterns):
    """
    >>> num_seq(['GAT','GAC','ATCG','ATA','GTA'])
        ['G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'A']
    """
    lst = patterns[:]
    answer = [c for c in lst[0]]
    comp = [lst[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(patterns)):
        answer.extend(patterns[i][diff_idxl(comp,patterns[i]):])
        comp.append(patterns[i])
    return answer
```

I could get correct result with this code.

```
>>> num_seq(['GAT','GAC','ATCG','ATA','GTA'])
    ['G', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'A']
>>> # (index + 1) means a node in Trie structure.
```

---

Updated in 2015.04.17
I wrote a additional code to get what I want.

```
>>> # What I want to get is this... 
>>> strings = ['GAT','GACA','ATC','GATG']
>>> nseq = num_seq(strings)
    ['G','A','T','C','A','A','T','C','G']
>>> make_matrix_trie(strings)
    [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 0, 0, 9]]
```

My implementation of make_matrix is this.

```
def make_matrix_trie(patterns):
    m = []
    for pat in patterns:
        m.append([0]*len(pat))

    comp = num_seq(patterns)
    comp.append(0)

    idx = 1
    for i in range(len(patterns)):
        for j in range(len(patterns[i])):
            if patterns[i][j] == comp[0]:
                m[i][j] = idx
                idx += 1
                comp.pop(0)
            else:
                m[i][j] = 0
            print (m,comp)
    return m
```

But the result was not what I expected.

```
>>> make_matrix_trie(['GAT','GACA','ATC','GATG'])
    [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> # expected result:
>>> # [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 0, 0, 9]]
```

With some help, I think I can correct and complete my code.

Comment: Can you describe the desired process in words? It is unclear what you're after by just looking at those examples.
If you describe the transformation more precisely, you can perhaps come up with a solution by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't figured out your masking and integer assignment scheme. Does this have to do with nucleotides? Some elaboration would help.

I can help with the final step, however. Here's a one-liner to convert your integer lists to "tuple lists."

```
def listToTupleList(l):
    return [(l[i-1],l[i]) if i!=0 else (0,l[i]) for i in range(len(l))]
```